# PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, configuration

I have installed Instagram-PHP library https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API
via

```
composer require mgp25/instagram-php
```

this created a '/vendor' folder in my project (projects folder is "TinderAI").

I've created an 'TinderAI/index.php; file containing:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram();
```

(this 'require' address is in the README file of the library).
Whenever i ran

```
php index.php
```

I got error in my /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log file:

> [03-Oct-2018 11:50:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:
> require(/Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/../vendor/autoload.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/index.php on line 3
>
> [03-Oct-2018
> 11:50:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening
> required '/Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/../vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/lib/php') in
> /Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/index.php on line 3

there is /examples folder in the library to test it. If I ran any example file, for example "php accessingValues.php" I get similar error (now with the name of the executed file):

> [02-Oct-2018 16:08:13 UTC] PHP Warning:
> require(/Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/examples/../vendor/autoload.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/examples/accessingValues.php
> on line 6
>
> [02-Oct-2018 16:08:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require():
> Failed opening required
> '/Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/examples/../vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/lib/php') in
> /Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/examples/accessingValues.php
> on line 6

I think this is a very basic level mistake with paths to the files in php, but I can't figure it out. Would be glad if you can help me.

Comment: Question 1: Does the file actually exist? What happens when you type `ls /Users/sergeyfomin/code/vendor/composer/../psy/psysh/src/Psy/functions.php` ? Is the file there. I think you will need to install (via composer) whatever library which should exist under `psy/psych`

Comment: Question 2: OMG! Why are you directly editing files installed in composer's  `vendor` folder to include hardcoded references to another 'vendor' library? That's gonna get really painful. I think you need to understand what composer is actually supposed to do, and how namespacing and autoloading works in PHP. A bit of research now could save you a lot of hassle down the line!

Comment: Thanx, i've edited the first error message. There was some unnessecary forgotten "vendor" folder just on the upper level of my "TinderAI" project and require in index.php was refferering to it. I've deleted that unnecessary folder and now the errror message is more relevant.

Comment: /Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/../vendor/autoload.php should be /Users/sergeyfomin/code/tinderAI/vendor/autoload.php (without ..)  that's the problem.

Comment: " OMG! Why are you directly editing files installed in composer's vendor folder to include hardcoded references to another 'vendor' library?" is that about the second error message? f

Comment: No. It was about the original message I saw before you edited your question. Part of that comment is no longer relevant. However, you might still want to attempt to autoload the relevant code library instead of using include.

Comment: what do you mean by "instead of using include"? If it's related to "require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php' " - that how the author of the library writes in his documentation: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API I did everything as he writes.

Comment: I've looked at the github library. The examples supplied are not meant to run in place, but moved to your web-servers public folder, and then run from there. BTW: Are you aware what `..` means in a file path? It's a way of indicating one folder higher.

Comment: Use `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`. The `vendor` folder is in the same folder as your `index.php`

Comment: thank you Ben and Kerbholz. Yes, I understand that .. means one folder higher and I tried that before and it worked... I just thought that I do something wrong because the author wrote it with ".." in his github README and in files in 'examples' folder....